# Access Cloud Run URL for GCP authenticated users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-iam

Using IAM, is there any simple way to let a GCP console logged in user to access a Cloud Run URL?

The idea here is to have a lightweight way to protect the access to some URLs for people who are *already* logged in to the console.

So I don't want the world to have access, only my GCP users.

It seems that the options are either:

- Setup IAP for Cloud Run => costly (load balancer) and not exactly simple
- Setup the container to require authentication, generate a token from the console, use a browser extension and inject the said token on each request.

Note: I tried to setup a container as allowing non authenticated calls but removing the allUsers principal from the Invoker role and stick to a particular email address. The URL ended up still being available to non authenticated browsers.

Seems like a very simple use case but unless I am missing something, the options are all over-the-top.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might work for you (don't necessarily know if it's the best architecture)

1. Deploy cloud run and ONLY allow for aunthenticated invocation
2. Create a very simple GAE project. Add `login: required` to `app.yaml` so that anyone trying to load the app is forced to login
3. Your GAE code can then invoke the cloud run endpoint. Your code will generate a token and include it as a header when making the call to the cloud run endpoint. See this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/secure-services#review-integration)

Comment: Thanks. This, however, will not be a suitable solution as the container I want to access is a webapp that has a login / registration flow which also captures a jwt to send it to backend resources (other containers). So I will end up with 2 jwt.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#run-service-to-service-example-go , I deployed a Cloud Function with unauthenticated access and basic auth in the code itself. Requests to the CF are forwarded to my CR service. (I use it for accessing diagnostics paths only).